# How to separate output per processed file

Tags: powershell

Long story short, I would like to find a way to accomplish the following in Powershell.

I have to process a ton of XML files and validate them against a specific XSD.
The output (Verbose) has to be stored in separate files with each file containing the name of the processed file.
After a ton of research, I can't seem to find an answer to my problem so here we are.

This is the setup:

```
FileABC.xml
File123.xml
FileA1B2C3.xml
```

Script that I have, so far

```
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\path\to\files\*.xml
$VerbosePreference = "continue"


foreach ($file in $files) {
Test-Xml $file -SchemaPath '.\Magnet.xsd' -Verbose | Out-File -FilePath "${file}.txt"
}
```

When I execute the script above, I get the Verbose output in my command line and no seperate files.

If I execute the following

```
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\path\to\files\*.xml
$VerbosePreference = "continue"


foreach ($file in $files) {
Test-Xml $file -SchemaPath '.\Magnet.xsd' -Verbose *>> output.txt
}
```

Then I get all the output that I need in one big file but without the filenames ofcourse. This makes the file unreadable.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**SOLUTION**

```
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\path\to\files\*.xml
$VerbosePreference = "continue"


foreach ($file in $files) {
  ( $(Test-Xml $file -SchemaPath '.\Magnet.xsd' -Verbose),
    "--- $($file.FullName) ---",
    "`n"
  ) *>> output.txt
}
```

It will generate one file that contains all the results and adds one 'new line' after processing each file to make the file more readeable.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `*>> ${file}.txt`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I used the following code now
    `foreach ($file in $files) {
    Test-Xml $file -SchemaPath '.\Magnet.xsd' *>> ${file}.txt
    }`
But when executing, nothing is shown on the command line nor do I have seperate files (actually nothing is created)

Comment: Still with the `-Verbose` switch

Comment: `foreach ($file in $files) {
Test-Xml $file -SchemaPath '.\Magnet.xsd' -Verbose *>> ${file}.txt
}`
Same result. I don't know if it matters but I have version 4 of PS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect an array to the `output.txt` e.g. as follows

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
  ( '---',                          <# separator #>
    $file.FullName,                 <# file identification #>
    $(Test-Xml $file -SchemaPath '.\Magnet.xsd' -Verbose)
  ) *>> output.txt
}
```

or

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
  ( 
    "--- $($file.FullName) ---",     <# separator AND file identification in one line #>
    $(Test-Xml $file -SchemaPath '.\Magnet.xsd' -Verbose)
  ) *>> output.txt
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I went for the second option and changed the order which turned out great! However, I have one additional question. When I open the output.txt, everything is appended beneath eachother. Question: How can I add an 'enter' between processing of files?

Comment: Sorry for the spamming but I found the answer to my question ;) "`n" did the trick

Comment: @Dragonix `"--- $($file.FullName) ---\`n\`n"` should produce the same output as your solution `"--- $($file.FullName) ---","\`n"` IMHO.